# oSUSE and ubuntu: error15 on GRUB

Tags: 11.10, grub2

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 from opensuse 11, by this method:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet

now grub gives error 15 (i think it's Ubuntu's grub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can usually be fixed by reinstalling GRUB2 to the Master Boot Record. Usually we direct people to use one of [these methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2), which involve having a usable live CD of Ubuntu or a similar GNU/Linux distribution.

That's what you'll have to do if none of your installed operating systems are bootable (though you can probably use your openSUSE CD/DVD or bootable USB flash drive for this, if you have one). However, if you are able to boot into openSUSE, then you should be able to reinstall GRUB2 to the Master Boot Record in openSUSE. To do that, I recommend using the [chroot method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#ChRoot) to chroot from your openSUSE system into your Ubuntu system and reinstall its GRUB2.